# Google email markup issues

Tags: google-schemas

We do not have the event markup feature in our HTML code, but Google is generating the event markup card at the top of the email anyway sometimes and pulling in the company's address (wrong address for this use case). We'd like to disable this feature, but we do not know how given we do not have the code in the email to begin with. Is there also any data on how often this can happen?